# Изменение пароля REST API VMware vCloud Director

Tags: php

Подскажите.
Работаю с VMware vCloud Director 5.6.
получаю XML с инфой о пользователе, добавляю элемент `<Password>123456789</Password>`
И отправляю его обратно. Ругается на элемент Password.
Кто работал с этой штукой? Как обновить пароль пользователя?

Описание методов

[PUT /admin/user/{id}](http://pubs.vmware.com/vcd-56/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vcloud.api.reference.doc_56%2Fdoc%2Foperations%2FPUT-User.html)

[GET /admin/user/{id}](http://pubs.vmware.com/vcd-56/index.jsp#operations/GET-User.html)

В интернете об этом ничего нет. Почти уверен, что ответ не получу, но мало ли вдруг...

Answer (score 1):

Все! Решил.
Элементы должны быть в правильной последовательности
Элемент **Password** должен находиться перед элементом **GroupReferences**